# Python, best way to override functions for optimization

Tags: python, optimization, overriding, overloading

Not sure how to best describe this questions, but I am just trying to optimize things, since I perform these 100s of millions of times.  So I am trying to eliminate logic as much as possible.  So for simplicity lets take a simple class below:

```
class Steps():
   def __init__(self, descending, value):
      self.descending = descending
      self.value = value

   def step(self):
      if self.descending:
         self.value -= 1
      else:
         self.value += 1

   def other_funcs1(self):
      pass

   def other_funcs2(self):
      pass

a = Steps(descending=True, value=0)
b = Steps(descending=False, value=0)

a.step() # say this is done 100 million times
b.step() # say this is done 100 million times
```

Since we already know if its descending/ascending in the beginning, it seems unnecessary to have the logic 'if self.descending' inside that step(), especially if we are calling it millions of times.

One way to get this better is inheriting a base class like:

```
class Steps():
   def __init__(self, value):
      self.value = value

   def other_funcs1(self):
      pass

   def other_funcs2(self):
      pass

class StepsInc(Steps):
   def __init__(self, value):
      Steps.__init__(self, value)
   
   def step(self):
      self.value += 1

class StepsDec(Steps):
   def __init__(self, value):
      Steps.__init__(self, value)
   
   def step(self):
      self.value -= 1

a = StepsDec(value=0)
b = StepsInc(value=0)

a.step() # say this is done 100 million times
b.step() # say this is done 100 million times
```

The above should be more optimal since we are no longer doing unnecessary 'if' statements.  But what if I have multiple functions, that depend on different parameters, how should I do it?  So instead of just 'descending' i have other parameters that can have different functions.  I dont want to have too many classes and can seem messy.

One solution I thought of is instead of inherting, I can do something like this, though not sure if this is pythonic:

```
class Steps():
       def __init__(self, descending, value):
          self.descending = descending
          self.value = value
          self.step = self.stepDec if self.descending else self.stepInc # can have multiple of this for different functions and parameters
          # more potential example
          #self.func = self.func1 if self.new_param else self.func2

       def stepInc(self):
          self.value += 1

       def stepDec(self):
          self.value -= 1

       def other_funcs1(self):
          pass

       def other_funcs2(self):
          pass

    
    
    a = Steps(descending=True, value=0)
    b = Steps(descending=False, value=0)
    
    a.step() # say this is done 100 million times
    b.step() # say this is done 100 million times
```

So this one seems cleaner than the other class that inherits a base class.  And I can have many of other functions that can be based on different parameters.  So two questions: 1) is this pythonic?, if not whats the better way to do it 2) How can I override default functions like "_ *repr* _" ?

So for the second question, lets say for print(a) I want to print "I am descending" and for print(b) I want to print "I am ascending".  I know this doesnt make much sense, but just wondering how I can override those.  I can definitely do it with the inheriting class example where each would just have its own "_ *repr* _" function.  But is there a way to do it with the latest example I have? Since this seems cleaner especially with more functions depending on different parameters.

Hope this question is clear. Thanks for the help

Comment: For your second question about printing.  On your last example, you'd just do like you did for setting self.step.  self.step_str = "descending" if self.descending else "ascending".  Then pass that to your print().

Comment: duh, why didnt I think of that.  Thanks! Guess the original problem was more complicated and didnt seem that straight forward cuz other values needed to be passed as well. But you definitely answered my question lol.  Is this pythonic though? Or is there a better naming convention I could do to make sure its a function not a variable?

Comment: If you increment/decrement by one depending on other values, I wonder whether you can add a field `_delta` to your class. That field is either 1 or -1 and is update whenever one of the parameters change. In the `step()` function you just do `self.value += self._delta`. No more `if` and `else` but now you have to add a non-constant value.

Comment: Yea i guess for this example that works, but the real problem actually steps by quantity.  And that quantity changes every step.  Yea I know its hard to try to depict actual problem with simplified version, but I'll definitely consider that kinda of solution in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there's a pretty approach to solve your problem. And the solution is just add a method dynamically to an object by injecting it in the constructor. As, the solution is simple, so I'm just providing the code:

```py
# note: in this approach the method only exists with object instance
#       the method has nothing to do with class

# note this import

import types

def desc(self):
    self.value -= 1

def inc(self):
    self.value += 1

class Steps():
    def __init__(self, func, descending, value):
        # add func as a method
        # where the method name is step
        self.step = types.MethodType(func, self)
        # nothing changes here
        self.descending = descending
        self.value = value

a = Steps(desc, True, 0)
b = Steps(inc, False, 0)

a.step();
print("value of a: {}".format(a.value));

b.step();
print("value of b: {}".format(b.value));
```

And the output is:

```
value of a: -1
value of b: 1
```

Now, you may be surprised to hear: **I would not recommend it for anyone**

Let me explain why:

1. First if you create a lot of objects in this way, there's a lot of method needs to be associated with those objects. It is possible that you may waste a lot of memory.
2. Object instances are binded with methods does not belong with class. This may create confusion for people, who are reading your code.
3. If you are following a tight oop coding style, you're just leaving those functions out in the open, or may be just wrapped in a class, but this is not a proven way to solve this problem.

I know, performance is a great concern for you, but still I would recommend to look at `strategy pattern`. A few more class won't hurt you, when you'd undertand how much flexibility those few classes will give you. And everyone who knows the pattern will understand your code just by a glance.

Now, I have said a lot. But, one last thing I would like to mention, if you are really very much interested in `performance`, you may `write an extension` or `switch to a compiled(faster) language`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  Question, isn't this example you have a strategy pattern, but you wont recommend it?

Comment: @user1179317 Its looks like strategy pattern. But its not the correct version. Specially, the approach to implementation. Its better to implement "Strategy Pattern" by programming to an interface(or, you may also say, programming to a supertype). But in this example, that aspect is really missing. I hope, it is clear to you now.

Comment: Honestly, Its not clear to me what the difference is.  But I'll just try to search for it.  Thanks though

Comment: @user1179317 Again, you can argue, if it is "Strategy paterrn" or not and can go a great length to that discussion, but in my perspective it's better not to call it "Strategy pattern".When, I think about patterns, two thoughts very important to me: 1. their way of solving problems and 2. their way of  implementation. If any of them going off track, I call that a bad version of that pattern, and don't recommend it. It would be much better to make you understand, if python has `interface` construct, where we use `interface` as a `supertype` for `strategy objects`.(I know python has `ABC` though)

Comment: Thank you very much.  I fully understand what you meant